# How can I update my url using window.location?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append the href values like #about to the end of my url, at the moment I have a var newURL that gets window.location and adds the contents of the href but now I have this I'm not sure how I actually replace the url in my browser?

**JS**

```
var newURL = window.location + href; //href= #about
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.location.hash = "about"
```

Should do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple of methods.

- Modify the `window.location.hash`
- Use the new [HTML5 History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) (use hash as fallback for older browser tho)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.hash` as other answered.

but if you want to rich operation on it the you should go for any library like 
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/